# Rails 4 deep nesting with routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, nested-resources

Here is my route.rb:

```
  resources :books, :path => "librairie" do
      resources :chapters, shallow: true
  end


  resources :chapters do 
     resources :titles, shallow: true
  end
  resources :titles
```

Here's my models:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :chapters
end

class Chapter < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :book
has_many :titles
end

class Title < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :chapter
end
```

What I would like to do is choose a book in the library and see a page with all the chapters and titles (belonging to each chapter). This works. (library = AllBooks || Book#Show = Book with all chapters and titles)

Then, click on the title and get a page to see the text corresponding. This also works. (Title#Show)

Now I would like to add a button back at the top of the view of Title#Show with the following:

> title of the book : chapter : title and with a link which go to the book (Book#Show)

However, after spending time in the controller I begin to be completely lost and my result looks worse and worse. How do I add such a button?

Comment: How are your models laid out?  `Book has_many :chapters` and `Chapters has_many :titles`? with just `belongs_to`?

Comment: Thanks for your editing and reply. Models : Books : class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :chapters
end
class Chapter < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :course
has_many :pages
end   class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :chapter
end

Comment: Hi Cagliostro, and Welcome to SO.  Can you please edit your original question to show your models instead of in a comment?  It's much easier for us to read.

Comment: @Daiku Sorry I m quite new here and I have still to learn how to ask correctly something, thanks a lot for your feedback.

Comment: No Worries, All Good!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so you can do this

```
class Title < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :chapter
  has_one :book, through: :chapter
end
```

Then in your controller you can do

```
class TitlesController
  def show
    @title = Title.find(params[:id])    
    @book = @title.book
  end  
end
```

Which means in your view you can do

```
<%= link_to book_path(@book) do %>
  <%= "#{ @book.title } #{ @chapter.title } #{ @title.title }" %>
<% end %>
```

I assume you're finding chapter in a `before_action` here.

Comment: Super !! Great thanks to you. So has I don't still master yet Rails I have found this solution based on yours  :  <br/>  `def show`
  <br/> `@title = Title.find(params[:id])`<br/>
  `@chapter = @lesson.chapter`<br/>
  `@Book = @chapter.book `<br/>     
`end` <br/> Cause Book was not recognised otherwise. Not sure to understand this line: `has_one :book, through: :chapter` but I will look in the rails guide, I have probably miss something in the association. Thanks a lot